# angular4 ngSubmit fires multiple times when submit button clicked multiple times?

Tags: angular

I have a multiple forms in my application,

When user click on submit button multiple times in any forms, records also saved multiple times in database?

I try to but the loader on submit click, but before loader displaying the user clicked the submit multiple times?

1, This is my form html :

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && createUpdateTenantUser()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<div>
**Have some form field**
</div>
<button class="btn btn-warning primary-action-btn" *ngIf="isCreate">Save User</button>
</form>
```

2, This is my component file :

```
  private createUpdateTenantUser() {
  this.spinner.show();
  this.objDataService.PostData(Controller.AdminController, 
  Method.CreateUpdateTenantUser,
  this.objUserModel)
  .subscribe((data) => {
   if (data === true && data != null) {           
        this.router.navigate(['/Home/ManageTenants/UsersView']);
      }
    this.spinner.hide();
  });
```

}

Comment: Provide the sample code...like your forms, submit events..etc..

Comment: You can set the button to be disabled after the first click (until any changes are done in the form or anything else).

Comment: I can't disable the button. The validations in the form is working correctly i need to know why angular ngSubmit allow the users to submit multiple time?

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of button is `type="submit"`

You should make button as `type="button"` and `(click) ="submit1()"`

Or make separate form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit1()">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<form (ngSubmit)="submit2()">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When i try to change the type="button" the from is not working validation is not triggered? I can't use two submit in single html file, i have only one form in single html.

Comment: please close form tag </form> for both forms. and put button inside the form.